# 'Close-window' keyboard shortcut in Libreoffice

Tags: 16.04, shortcut-keys, libreoffice

I'm using multiple documents in Libreoffice, in separate windows. Currently, `Ctrl-Q` [exits](https://help.libreoffice.org/Common/General_Shortcut_Keys_in#Shortcut_keys_for_controlling_documents_and_windows) the application, closing all windows. I want to remap `Ctrl-Q` so that it only closes the current window (as `Alt-F4` does). However, using Tools -> Customize, this seems impossible: the only relevant function under 'Application' is 'Exit'. Is there any way to edit the keyboard shortcuts so that `Ctrl-Q` does the same thing as `Alt-F4`?

Comment: I'm not at my machine right now, but if I remember right, Ctrl+Q is an application-specific keyboard shortcut. So in LibreOffice, you can go into "**Tools** - **Customize** - **Keyboard**" and make changes there.

Comment: Hmmm, I don't know about that but `Ctrl+W`  closes the current window, and (on my keyboard, at least) is *right next to* `Q`. :)

Comment: On my LibO, Ctrl+Q was unmapped so, under Tools, Customize, Keyboard, I set it to Close. (In Category, choose Documents. In Function, choose Close.)

Comment: DK Bose's suggestion did the trick: Documents -> Close is the behavior I want.

Answer (score 0):

From menus open Tools>Customize
On second tab name "Keyboard" in "Shortcut key" section find "Ctrl+Q" select it then click on  <kbd>Modify</kbd>  on the right side.
Below `"Functions"` under `"Category"` find `"Documents"` and select it. In next list which is named `"Function"` select `"Close"`.
The next one named `"Keys"` know should show `"Ctrl+Q"`
Press  <kbd>Ok</kbd> and have a good time.